# How can we pass azure monitor alertcontext data as parameters to Azure automation runbook

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-automation, azure-monitor

I have setup an Azure monitor alert for Cosmos. Configured action groups to call azure automation runbook using webhooks. Now, I want to pass the alertContext data as parameters to my automation runbook's powershell code.

I have tried below terraform code to acheive this. But it is not working.

```
resource "azurerm_automation_webhook" "whook" {
  name = "cosmos-webhook"
  resource_group_name = "cosmosrg"
  automation_account_name = "autoacc"
  expiry_time  = "2025-12-31T00:00:00Z"
  runbook_name = "runbookname"
  parameters = {
    "databaseName" = "{alertContext.resourceName}",
    "containerName" = "{alertContext.condition.allOf[0].source}"
  }
}
```

Could you please guide me on how we can pass data to automation runbook from monitor alerts using Terraform.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide the error/output on your terraform console for the parameters you are parsing? Variables are normally parse with a ${} or ${var.name}

```py
    "databaseName" = ${alertContext.resourceName},
    "containerName" = ${alertContext.condition.allOf[0].source}
```